# Swift webview PROXY

Tags: ios, swift, webview, proxy

With the code below I create a webview navigating to a URL. It works perfectly. But I need this navigation to be through an HTTP proxy.
How do I put proxy in a webview?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.iphub.info")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no simple way to achieve that.

You may intercept deprecated `UIWebView` with custom `NSURLProtocol` subclass, which utilizes `NSURLSession` inside. You'd easily set HTTP proxy configuration to the `connectionProxyDictionary` property of the `NSURLSessionConfigurtion`. Here's the [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CustomHTTPProtocol/Introduction/Intro.html). That would work, but you may see slightly worse performance than with WKWebView.

Alternatively, you may consider using `NetworkExtension.framework`, if the proxy server supports tunneling. Here's a [sample project](https://github.com/zqqf16/IKEv2_Demo) which utilizes Network Extension.